# C# generic method declaration issue

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say we want to build an assembly line consisting of multiple assembly parts, each of which takes something as an input, processes it and then passes it on to the next part.

Imagine the following assembly line following this convention: `[In-Type|Out-Type]`

```
[String|DateTime]-[DateTime|Int32]-[Int32|Double]-[Double|String]
```

how would the class for such an assembly part look like?

```
abstract class AssemblyPart<Tin, TOut> {

    AssemblyPart<TOut, ???> Next { get; private set; }
    AssemblyPart<???, TIn> Previous { get; private set; }

    abstract TOut OnProcess(TIn obj);
    public TOut Process(TIn obj) {
        TOut processedObj = OnProcess(obj);
        Next?.Process(processedObj);
    }

    public void Connect(AssemblyPart<???, TIn> part){
        Next = part;
        part.Previous = this;
    }
    public void ConnectTo(AssemblyPart<TOut, ???> part){
        Previous = part;
        part.Next = this;
    }

}
```

.. with what do I have to replace the `???` to make this work?
Since I don't really care what type `???` is (I don't need to know) I figured I can use `Object` or `dynamic` but this didn't bring me further

Comment: Sounds like you need `TPrev` and `TNext`, but it looks like your constricting yourself by using generics like this.

Comment: @gunr2171 I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: I agree, IMO, the generics aren't providing you much benefit and are actively getting in the way.  You would have to make `Connect` and `ConnectTo` generic, with their own type parameters.

Comment: @gunr2171  what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: I'm not sure that the individual parts should know about each other.  You could however find ways to  combine a <int, stirng> <string, char> to create a <int, char> though.

Comment: You might want to look into the way it's implemented in the TPL dataflow libraries (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). Sounds the same to me.

Comment: @Amy I don't want to mess with all to many `Object`s .. that would be very annoying if you had to cast and validate their tyes all the time

Comment: @juharr the idea is to separate it to be able to reduce it to an atomic level where you can combine them freely and build complex but still easy to "use"/implement these processes

Comment: @TobiasWürth I'm saying combine them in a layered approach instead of a linked one.  A method like `AssemblyPart<TIn, TOther> Combine<TOther>(AssemblyPart<TOut, TOther> next)` would be what I'm thinking of.

Comment: Why does a given part need to know what comes before it?  Why does it need to know what comes after it?  What do either of those things have to do with how it processes the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your design you've required your type to not only know what it takes in, and what it takes out, but also what the thing that it takes in takes in as input, and what the thing it sends its result to does with its output, and then you need to know what provides the input to the thing that provides the input to what you take in, and the thing that is outputted by the thing that you provide your output to, and so on, forever, in both directions.

So change your class to not need to know that.  Your type needs to not have an `AssemblyPart` that provides the input, and an `AssemblyPart` that takes the output.  You need to have something that *just* provides a value, and something that *just* takes in a value.  `AssemblyPart` can then take in some type of value, and provide some other type of value, and it can use *anything* that can provide a value for its input, whether that's an assembly part or something else, and it can give its output to anything that can accept the values, not just other assembly parts.  Not only does this mean that each assembly part doesn't need to know how the input gets its input, and how its output uses it, but it means you can have other types of things in the chain, for example something that produces values with no inputs (i.e. something to start the chain) and something that uses values but provides no others (i.e. something that can end the chain).

Comment: What one calls 'give' is 'take' for the other. can you provide a minimalistic example? Maybe I'm just not seeing something here

Comment: @TobiasWürth Your current code doesn't actually ever do anything meaningful with the previous value.  All you do with the next value is call a method that takes in a `TOut` and doesn't need to return anything.  So all you need is an interface that has a method with one parameter and no output for your next value, and an interface that does nothing at all for your previous value.

Comment: I would still appreciate an example. I will look into it and try some examples. But I'm not sure if this is going to work if I want to be able to 'navigate' the assembly line with `previous` and `next` properties

Comment: @TobiasWürth I can't provide an example without knowing what you want an example *of*.

Comment: let's go with the example I gave in the question. an assembly line which takes an input, process it (potentially changing it's type) and then passing it on to the next one

Comment: @TobiasWürth In your example, you never do anything with your previous value, and all you do with your next value is call a method taking a `TOut`, so like I said, `Next` should be of a type that has a method taking in a `TOut` and returning nothing, `Previous` needs to be of a type that doesn't need to do anything.  There you go.  If you need the code, `interface Next<T>{Process(T t);} interface Previous {}`  Use those as the types of `Next` and `Previous`.  Have `AssemblyPart` implement `Next<TIn>` and `Previous`.

Comment: the processing should occur in `abstract TOut OnProcess(TIn obj);` .. this is just a base part. the idea is to override this in an implementing class

Comment: @TobiasWürth Yes, I'm aware of that.  Why in the world would the actual processing implementation need to know or care about what the previous part was, or what the next part is?  It gets the value it needs as its input, and produces its value, and doesn't need to care where the input comes from or where the output goes.

Comment: I got [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h4d82l9c32ht0qo/devenv_2018-01-19_21-23-45.png) now. The problem I see with this is that I cannot navigate the assembly (e.g. 5 steps backwards, or 3 steps forward). I also cannot connect them fluently `(e.g. new Pipe().connect(..).connect(..)`

Comment: @TobiasWürth Connecting a pipe to another isn't creating a new pipe, so of course you can't perform an action on a non-existent result.  You could create a method that took two parts, connected them, and returned an object that represented performing both actions, which you can then pass to the same method with another part, and so on.  That would be a proper composition method for parts.  As I've said, there's no reason for any part to know or care about all of the other parts. It doesn't make sense to expect every part to be able to tell you about every other part.  Why do they need to know?

Comment: interesting. I think I start to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed  to work with different types

Comment: @TobiasWürth Not sure how what will work, and why is it not already working with different types?

Comment: it needs to know what comes after it because it needs to invoke the next processing method. which means the item needs to know what type gets accepted by the next instance. it also accepts some type. which means that each type has to know about two types, the one coming in and the one going out. these two types don't have to be the same. now how do you chain them up or even define a parent interface declaring some method with parameters when every child instance can have a different type?

Comment: .. maybe I just can't see the forest for the trees anymore. You seem to have a pretty clear idea. please just provide a working example defining an assembly lines with multiple different types like you vision it

Comment: @TobiasWürth When you chain two operations, creating an operation that performs one operation, then provides the result to the next, then all any consumer of that result needs to know is the type of the input, and the type of the output, not the intermediate type.  That statement holds true even when you continue to chain items again and again.

Comment: At the end of the day you don't actually need a new type at all.  You want a type that represents any arbitrary operation that takes an input and provides an output.  That's `Func<TIn, TOut>`.  You can write a method to chain two of them as follows: `public static Func<TIn, TOut> Chain<TIn, TIntermediate, TOut>(Func<TIn, TIntermediate> first, Func<TIntermediate, TOut> second) => param => second(first(param));`  You can now chain operations , or invoke chained operations, as much as you want.  That does everything your type does.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to add types in your class for the previous and next types. The way you've written the code so far, each `AssemblyPart` MUST know the datatype that comes before and after it, so you need to pass that along.

```
abstract class AssemblyPart<Tin, TOut, TPrev, TNext>
```

Actually, however, you're going to run into MAJOR problems when using a `AssemblyPart` inside your class. You can't have

```
AssemblyPart<TOut, TNext> Next { get; private set; }
AssemblyPart<TPrev, TIn> Previous { get; private set; }
```

Each of those need *4* generic arguments. You need to know what the previous and next of *each of them are* when you set them up. It be more like:

```
AssemblyPart<TOut, TNext, TIn, TNextNext> Next { get; private set; }
AssemblyPart<TPrev, TIn, TPrevPrev, TOut> Previous { get; private set; }
```

But now you need to pass those into the class's arguments, and that will force you to update the arguments on your properties, which will force you to update class's arguments...

This will compound on itself until you decide enough is enough.

Comment: I see. Thanks for putting this together. But I agree, this isn't very useful.